# Get my function to return my Object - axios API

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I just started this week with JS and struggle a lot with fixing my function.

```js
function createCurrencyList(){
  var currencyList;
  axios.get('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/47539a177655054cd59b80b6/latest/USD')
   .then(result =>{
    currencyList = new CurrencyObjConstructor(
      result.data.time_last_update_utc,
      result.data.conversion_rates.EUR,
      //and a lot more conversion rates
    );
      return currencyList;
    })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log(error);
   
  })
};
```

So I tried a ton of variations of rewriting, changing focus and even using other examples of getting Data from an API but nothing works for me.

All I need is to let my function return something(here currencyList)

If anyone has a little more experience and can help me to navigate me how to get a succesful return I would greatly aprreciate that.

Kind regards

Comment: You're not returning the promise chain.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `return` statement before the word axios

If you want, you can try using async/await:

```js
async function createCurrencyList() {
  try {  
    const response = await axios.get('https://v6.exchangerate- 
    api.com/v6/47539a177655054cd59b80b6/latest/USD')
    const currencyList = new CurrencyObjConstructor(
      response.data.time_last_update_utc,
      response.data.conversion_rates.EUR,
      // and a lot more conversion rates
    )
    return currencyList
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```